# Cloning tkinter Buttons with other function

Tags: python, tkinter, clone, tk-toolkit

right now I am working on a python phone book with following layout:

|Name | Surname |

Now I want to create a button for each contacts Name and Surname, so 2 buttons for 1 contact * n. If I press on the Name or Surname a box with more details of the contact should open.
Can anyone please help me?

I tried following so far:

```
prename = ["John", "Jack"]
surname = ["Tompson", "Daniels"]
x = 0
y = 0
for pn in prename:
    pre = Button(main, text=pn)
    pre.grid(row=x, column=0)
    x += 1
for sn in surname:
    sur = Button(main, text=sn)
    sur.grid(row=y, column=1)
    y += 1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to associate the buttons with the functions you want to be executed when you press them. I use `lambda` to pass the specific name to the function call.

Also; its more readable to use `enumerate` when you want a loop index.

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()

prename = ["John", "Jack"]
surname = ["Tompson", "Daniels"]

def get_prename(n): # Callback function for prename buttons
    print(n)

def get_surname(n): # Callback function for surname buttons
    print(n)

for x, pn in enumerate(prename):
    pre = Button(main, text=pn, command=lambda pn=pn: get_prename(pn))
    pre.grid(row=x, column=0)

for y, sn in enumerate(surname):
    sur = Button(main, text=sn, command=lambda sn=sn: get_surname(sn))
    sur.grid(row=y, column=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot, that's exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: @milli727 But you said that a box should open. It only prints.

Comment: I will suggest you to use `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(pn)`

Comment: Yes, but that was my main problem. I think I can figure the rest out by myself.

Comment: I try to bypass messageboxes because design is important to me and I wan't to change background, foreground, ...